# CSS Assign class to a class definition

Tags: css, wordpress

In Wordpress themes, in a first style.css there are the general definitions, in a custom.css you can add own styles. 
There, I'd like to address certain single elements like

```
home .example-class_1 h1 {}
```

In the theme I'm working with I can't do that inline, so I have to use the custom.css. 
Now, instead of repeating all single styles in the bracket I would like to assign the class which has already been defined in the style.css:

```
.heading-class_1 {font-size:1.2em;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; etc}
```

Is there any way to do that? As far as I know

```
home .example-class_1 h1 { .heading-class_1; }
```

is not allowed (just to be sure, I tested it, it does not work). Is there a workaround in CSS (not JS)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to use nested CSS, you'll have to use an extension, you can learn more about it, check out [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide).

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question in a different way: Obviously there's no comfortable shortcut - it looks like SASS allows me to add a class, and then translates it into common CSS. Which of course I could also do by hand :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that by default in CSS but you can use a preprocessor that can do that and then it'll compile it into vanilla (normal) CSS for you.

Check [Extend within Sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7). That'll do the trick. Other preprocessors out there might be able to do this too, but Sass is a popular choice.

Other than that, you'll have to do:

```
home .example-class_1 h1 { font-size:1.2em; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; }
```

Comment: Yes, SASS looks like a great tool for developing CSS, thanks for the hint! For my simple purpose just to save some space in the custom.css it might be too mighty. So I think I'll do it the classic way by writing the attributes myself...

Comment: Yes, if it's just this you're after, Sass is overkill. But in future if you want to write complex CSS then it's definitely a solid option.